# Ansible, is group_vars and host_vars dirs at multiple levels supported?

Tags: ansible

I am experimenting with variable overriding in Ansible. To do so, I have created the below-depicted directory structure. Note that under inventories, I have created two separate sites (1 & 2)
Also, note that I have added group_vars/host_vars at two different levels; below inventories and each site.

```
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── inventories
│   ├── group_vars
│   │   └── all.yml
│   ├── host_vars
│   │   └── target2.yml
│   ├── site1
│   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   └── all.yml
│   │   ├── host_vars
│   │   │   └── target1.yml
│   │   └── hosts.yml
│   └── site2
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── all.yml
│       ├── host_vars
│       │   └── target2.yml
│       └── hosts.yml
├── modules
├── playbooks
│   └── playbook1
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── all.yml
│       └── host_vars
└── roles
```

I would like to be able to store default variables for groups/hosts at "inventories" level and override them when/if necessary at site/group/host level using directories (not the hosts.yml), but I am unable to do so.

If I test the inventory by targeting the base "inventories" directory, I can see that group_vars/host_var folders under sites are ignored:

```
ansible-inventory --vars --graph -i inventories/

@all:
  |--@site1:
  |  |--target1
  |  |  |--{scope = inventories/site1/hosts.yml}
  |  |--target2
  |  |  |--{scope = inventories/host_vars/target2.yml}
  |--@site2:
  |  |--target2
  |  |  |--{scope = inventories/host_vars/target2.yml}
  |--@ungrouped:
  |--{scope = inventories/group_vars/all.yml}
```

But if I target a specific site, the underlying group_vars/host_var folder are used, but of course the one at base "inventory" are ignored:

```
ansible-inventory --vars --graph -i inventories/site1

@all:
  |--@site1:
  |  |--target1
  |  |  |--{scope = inventories/site1/host_vars/target1.yml}
  |  |--target2
  |  |  |--{scope = inventories/site1/group_vars/all.yml}
  |--@ungrouped:
  |--{scope = inventories/site1/group_vars/all.yml}

ansible-inventory --vars --graph -i inventories/site2

@all:
  |--@site2:
  |  |--target2
  |  |  |--{scope = inventories/site2/host_vars/target2.yml}
  |  |--{scope = inventories/site2/group_vars/all.yml}
  |--@ungrouped:
```

Is it possible to instruct ansible to look for group_vars/host_var folders in the entire directory structure?

Thanks!

Comment: `I would like to be able to store default variables for groups/hosts at "inventories" level and override them when/if necessary at site/group/host level using directories` <= I very strongly suggest you **don't** do that. Good practice is described in [ansible var precedence documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable): `We suggest that you define each variable in one place: figure out where to define a variable, and keep it simple`

Comment: In other words: having inventory and playbook level `group_vars` dir is not a problem but they should not hold the same variables. You can of course ignore my advice but you might experience serious headaches because variable precedence is not as straightforward as you first think (see above link).

Comment: Thank you for the heads-up. Right now I am just exploring the inheritance/override of variables. I will indeed consider your comment.

Answer (score 0):

According your description and example your sets `site1` and `site2` are already subsets of set `all`. You made the observation and described it in your question

> *If I target a specific site, the underlying group_vars/host_var folder are used, but of course the one at base "inventory" are ignored*

also the used command gives a hint

```bash
ansible-inventory --vars --graph -i inventories/site1 # or 2
```

since with this you'll set the root of a tree structure or graph to a sub tree or part of a graph.

> *Is it possible to instruct Ansible to look for group_vars/host_var folders in the entire directory structure?*

No, since there will be not other directory outside of the defined subset, sub tree or graph part.

> *but of course the one at base "inventory" are ignored*

In other words, the base "inventories" doesn't exists (anymore) since you've set the base to "inventories/site1" or 2.

---

An other approach could be to have one inventory for each site.

Comment: Hi @U88D, can you please explain better? Why inventories/group_var/all/*.yml would be different from inventories/group_var/all.yml. 
In each yml file of my example, I have defined a variable called "scope" and value equal the file path where it is defined to test variable overriding.

Comment: Hi @U88D, thanks for your edit, your comment on the following makes perfect sense
`ansible-inventory --vars --graph -i inventories/site1 # or 2`
Still I was curious if there is a way to instruct ansible to search recursively the directory tree for group_vars and host_vars when addressing the base directory
`ansible-inventory --vars --graph -i inventories/`